# Javascript function not working after postback?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here i am trying to increase the height of the iframe after postback but it is not working and the alert itself is not popping up.Here is my code

```
function increaseiframesize() {
alert("aaaaaa");
$('#MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis').height('523');
}
```

and

```
protected void lnkBTNSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e
{
TextBox txtTextBoxRetailGroup   = (TextBox)uscRetailParameters.FindControl("txtRetailCustomerGroup");
TextBox txtTextBoxPPGroup       = (TextBox)uscRetailParameters.FindControl("txtProductGroup");
if (txtTextBoxRetailGroup.Text != string.Empty && txtTextBoxPPGroup.Text != string.Empty && txtATrendStartDate.Text != string.Empty && txtATrendEndDate.Text != string.Empty)
{
this.IFTrendAnalysis.Attributes.Add("src", "");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptRegistration", "increaseiframesize();", true);
}
}
```

and

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<iframe id="IFTrendAnalysis" name="IFTrendAnalysis" scrolling="auto" runat="server"
width="100%" height="403" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBTNSalesTrendChart" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBTNSalesLiftChart" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkBTNSubmit" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBTNSalesLiftChart" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBTNTAEventROI" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBTNTrendAnalyzeTBL" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any suggestion???

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to call your method after the ajax request is sent and completed and control get back to browser. The javascript that is supposed to execute onload of form does not execute for ajax all. If it is ajax call then do this

Register endRequest event in javascript

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler)
```

Call your method here

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
    increaseiframesize();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by ajax call here??

Comment: You have update panel and trigger which means you are sending ajax call.

Comment: yes i gave it like this <script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) { increaseiframesize(); } 
</script>

Comment: Yes, its important where you put it. Just before ending of body tag would be good enough and should be out of update panel area.

Comment: but inside ContentPlaceHolder where i have to put??

Comment: Put is outside of ContentPlaceHolder

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed to ensure the Javascript method was available after each postback!